# Have 2 toString method?

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I have 3 classes. Attendant, car and garage.
All have their toString method.
But,

```
public class Attendant {

    private Cars assign;
    static ArrayList<Attendant> myAtt = new ArrayList<Attendant>();

    public Attendant(int staffNum, String id, boolean available, attNm name, Cars assign) {
        this.staffNum = staffNum;
        this.id = id;
        this.available = available;
        this.name = name;
        this.assign = assign;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Attendant [staffNum=" + staffNum + ", id=" + id + ", available=" + available + ", name=" + name
                + ", assign=" + assign + "]";
    }
}
```

Car:

```
public class Cars {

    private String carID;
    private String plateNum;
    private static String position;
    private static Attendant assignedTo;
    private long currTime;
    static String[] tempArray2 = new String[Garage.getCarsCapacity()];


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car:" + plateNum + " ID:" + carID + " Position:" + position + " Assigned to:" + assignedTo.getId() 
        + "(" + assignedTo.getName() + ")" + " Parked at:" + convert(currTime);
    }
}
```

So my 2 toString print ok.
The problem is that i get to modify attendant object to contain a car as parameter.So if I print all my attendants it will use its toString then for printing the assign part it goes printing the car toString.
I need it to print only the carID when I want to print my attendants.
I cant change the car toString cause I use it the way it is.
If I use the assign.getCarID my java crash.
I think its because some are attendants car parameter are null.
What should i do, please?

Ps: they are all printing arraylists of their corresponding object

Comment: Add a Null check on assign.getCarID

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toString an arraylist containing object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596460/tostring-an-arraylist-containing-object)

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice. I have already answered your question in another topic. If something is unclear, feel free to add a comment there.

Comment: Well thanks, but I can't solve this one. The toString worked but if I want to print the car of the attendant with the attendant toString, it prints all his details(from the car ToString method)

Comment: Maybe you want to print just the name of the Attendant. Then simply call attendant.getName() - it'll return string as well.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But every attendant is getting the name. Do you have a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to change your Attendant's toString method. Right now it's overly simple, printing out Cars's toString by printing out contents of the assign variable, and instead have it print out the specific Cars data that you want to display. This will usually mean calling getter methods from Cars. As an aside your Cars class looks to be broken, in that it holds information for a single Car as well as information for many cars. Why this is so is not clear.